Simple personal task management for Windows
There is one feature I've been unable to find having looked at dozens of products. To illustrate: Let's say I want to repair some damaged drywall. I will need to buy some materials for this purpose. In another task, I want to build a shed in a spot where I've accumulated some junk. Before I can build I need to contract someone to remove the junk. Once I've cleared the junk I'll be ready to use materials that I buy. I live in a rural area. Buying any tools or materials involves substantial journeys. So I've like to group some of these tasks together to avoid redundant travel. At the same time, when I complete the tasks of buying for the two projects (and deleting those items) I would like the dependent items to become 'current'.
I hope this makes sense! Is there anything like this? Simple.

Task Coach

Task Coach is a simple open source todo manager to keep track of
personal tasks and todo lists. It is designed for composite tasks, and
also offers effort tracking, categories, notes and more.


I find the default colors for tasks too pale. You can change them in the preferences menu :
Edit/Preferences/Task appearance
You can use Task Coach Portable with PortableApps.com
App Notes

Unofficial Update: The publisher stopped updating this app in 2019.
This package is an unofficial update to the portable version adding in
better portablization, an updated installer and launcher, and taskbar
pinning support.

What is a portable app?
System Requirements: Windows 10, 11 & WINE
There is also an AppImage for Linux
If you use it, don't forget to have backups of your .tsk file.

Thank you. Seems not too far from what I want. I am going to give it a whirl.

@BillBell If you have any questions (about PortableApps or Task Coach), I'll do my best to answer them. I've also tried several task managers. Task Coach is the one that suits me best.

I am not going to post an answer, since I know & love TackCoach (even if the Android version keeps crashing).  If either of you want something more full featured, take a look at https://abstractspoon.com/ ToDoList

Yon a simple interface for your thoughts is a new (in 2024), very simple software, probably a side-project from a sole developer. See 3-minute explainer video on Youtube.
If you like a minimalistic interface , the software being a a single web page running on your PC; this might be for you.
The concept is something between set of interlinked notes and to-do-lists, perhaps with some mind-map ideas thrown in.
In Yon, you can accomplish your requirements by editing self-defined links.

Thank you. Interesting but not too close to what I would like.
